# I'm trying to reload a div with AJAX in my Ruby App. The div carries an 'if condition'

Tags: javascript, html, ruby-on-rails, ruby

1. This is my  in my pages.home.html.erb

   ```
     <div id="favorites-div">
       <% if current_user.voted_for? item %>
         <%= link_to '<i class="fas fa-minus-square plus_and_minus_button"></i>'.html_safe, item_unlike_path(item.id)%> 
       <% else %>    
         <%= link_to '<i class="fas fa-plus-square plus_and_minus_button"></i>'.html_safe, item_like_path(item.id)%>
       <% end %>
     </div>
   ```
2. I am using a 'acts_as_votable' gem
3. I have nested these 2 get's in my items: routes:
   get 'like', to: 'items#like'
   get 'unlike', to: 'items#unlike'
4. In my items controller I have defined 2 methods:
   def like
   item = Item.find(params['item_id'])
   item.liked_by current_user
   redirect_back fallback_location: root_path
   end

   def unlike
   item = Item.find(params['item_id'])
   item.unliked_by current_user
   redirect_back fallback_location: root_path
   end

4.1 These two methods are available in the whole ItemsController class and they are not inside inside any of the CRUD methods.

My questions would be:
1. What JS function would you recommend? Do I remove and then add the ID in the div? 
2.Do I just load the div again? (.load)
3. Do i need to create a new file in my Rails app to implement this method?

Your kind help is very appreciated!

Comment: I would recommend placing the html you wish to re-render inside a separate partial file. This blog explains the general concept https://coderwall.com/p/kqb3xq/rails-4-how-to-partials-ajax-dead-easy

Answer (score 0):

The traditional way to do this in Rails has been to render a new HTML fragment on the server, and send it across to the browser wrapped in JavaScript that knows how to update the DOM with the new HTML when the browser received and evaluates it.

To do this you need to set up a few things:

- The fragment you want to render dynamically should be moved to a partial, so you can render it independently of any view
- You need an ID on the containing element, so you can easily figure out where to insert the re-rendered HTML
- You need a `.js` view that can render the partial, along with the JavaScript required to update the DOM.
- You should use remote links

Your HTML views should look something like this:

```
# pages.home.html.erb

<div id="favorites-div">
  <%= render 'votes' %>
</div>

# votes.html.erb

<% if current_user.voted_for? item %>
  <%= link_to '<i class="fas fa-minus-square plus_and_minus_button"></i>'.html_safe, item_unlike_path(item), data: { remote: true }%> 
<% else %>    
  <%= link_to '<i class="fas fa-plus-square plus_and_minus_button"></i>'.html_safe, item_like_path(item), data: { remote: true } %>
<% end %>
```

Your new JavaScript view should render the partial, and replace the existing HTML with the new HTML, using the `j` helper to escape JavaScript characters in the returned string:

```
# unlike.js.erb

$('#favorites-div').html('<%=j render 'votes' %>')
```

Comment: @meager, Thank you so so much for your help man! You're a king

Comment: @meager, There are several things I tried that didnt work:

Comment: @meager, There are several things I tried that didnt work:
# = at sign

1. I puted my prtial in my 'shared' folder and when I put: <%= render 'votes' %> in my 'home.html.erb' I get this eror: Mising partial pages/_votes, application/_votes

2. So then I moved the votes file to the 'pages' foldr were my 'home.html.erb' was and it couldnt find 'item' in the folowing code: <% if current_user.voted_for? item %>. So them I changed it to #items wich in my pages controler is #items = Item.all but then its says: undefined method id so I puted in my controler #item = Item.find(params[:id]) no work

Comment: @meager So I think the error is because at.items its a ActiveRecord:Relation object and not a model object... so it's not finding the id of the object... any clue how to solve this?